# Databricks Python kernel unresponsive on using umap.UMAP().fit_transform()

Tags: python-3.x, databricks

The databricks python kernel goes unresponsive when running the code snippet:

```
umap.UMAP().fit_transform(np.random.randn(10_000, 20))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------The Python process exited with exit code 134 (SIGABRT: Aborted).---------------------------------------------------------------------------The last 10 KB of the process's stderr and stdout can be found below. See driver logs for full logs.---------------------------------------------------------------------------Last messages on stderr:ite/binding/ffi.py", line 152 in __call__  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/executionengine.py", line 92 in finalize_object  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 1060 in wrapper  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 999 in _finalize_specific  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 797 in _finalize_final_module  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 765 in finalize  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 567 in _ensure_finalized  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/codegen.py", line 720 in add_linking_library  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/base.py", line 841 in _compile_subroutine_no_cache  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/base.py", line 863 in compile_subroutine  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/base.py", line 878 in compile_internal  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/arrayobj.py", line 6181 in array_argsort  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/base.py", line 1217 in wrapper  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/base.py", line 1187 in __call__  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 1182 in _lower_call_normal  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 940 in lower_call  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 1211 in lower_expr  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 675 in lower_assign  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 463 in lower_inst  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/parfors/parfor_lowering.py", line 53 in lower_inst  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 285 in lower_block  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 271 in lower_function_body  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 241 in lower_normal_function  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 187 in lower  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 466 in run_pass  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 273 in check  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 311 in _runPass  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35 in _acquire_compile_lock  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 356 in run  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 494 in _compile_core  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 535 in _compile_ir  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 470 in compile_ir  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 805 in compile_ir  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/parfors/parfor_lowering.py", line 1548 in _create_gufunc_for_parfor_body  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/parfors/parfor_lowering.py", line 340 in _lower_parfor_parallel_std  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/parfors/parfor_lowering.py", line 58 in _lower_parfor_parallel  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/parfors/parfor_lowering.py", line 51 in lower_inst  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 285 in lower_block  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 271 in lower_function_body  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 241 in lower_normal_function  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 187 in lower  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 466 in run_pass  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 273 in check  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 311 in _runPass  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35 in _acquire_compile_lock  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 356 in run  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 494 in _compile_core  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 528 in _compile_bytecode  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 460 in compile_extra  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 742 in compile_extra  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 152 in _compile_core  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 139 in _compile_cached  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 125 in compile  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 965 in compile  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 420 in _compile_for_args  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/umap/umap_.py", line 314 in nearest_neighbors  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/umap/umap_.py", line 565 in fuzzy_simplicial_set  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/umap/umap_.py", line 2566 in fit  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/umap/umap_.py", line 2887 in fit_transform  File "<command-4143099898583271>", line 26 in get_secondary_clusters_and_summaries  File "<command-4143099898583271>", line 50 in <cell line: 1>  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3524 in run_code  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3444 in run_ast_nodes  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3228 in run_cell_async  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78 in _pseudo_sync_runner  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3003 in _run_cell  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2957 in run_cell  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 528 in run_cell  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 389 in do_execute  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 722 in execute_request  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 398 in dispatch_shell  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 491 in process_one  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 502 in dispatch_queue  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80 in _run  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1890 in _run_once  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596 in run_forever  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 199 in start  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 707 in start  File "/databricks/python_shell/scripts/db_ipykernel_launcher.py", line 122 in <module>
```

I am using python version 3.9, umap-learn == 0.5.4 and the following additional libraries are also installed:

```
scikit-learn==1.2.1
transformers==4.30.2
sentence-transformers==2.2.2
numpy==1.24.1
numba==0.57.0
typing-extensions==4.8.0
```

Thanks in advance!

we have tried multiple versions of umap-learn but no luck!